# Search array of exact numbers in OpenOffice Calc regular expressions

Tags: regex, openoffice-calc

I have been trying to search for an list of numbers but i have not manage to make it work.

The closest i have gotten is to search by regular expressions using

> (283882|283778|283)

(See screenshot for example)

But that also matches "**283**977", "**283**938","**283**894" and so on.

How do i search for a exact list of numbers?

[Example screenshot (sorry for swedish text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCDlg.jpg)

Comment: Doesn't `\b(283882|283778|283)\b` work? OR `^(283882|283778|283)$`?

Comment: Yes! or almost!
Solved by using (^283882$|^283778$|^283$) you can add you answer "officially" if you want to or how ever it works!
Thank you so much

Comment: Are you sure it does not accept `^(283882|283778|283)$`?

Comment: I get no matches when doing that

Comment: Ok, then I guess I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *anchors*: `^` to match the beginning of a string, and `$` to match the end of the string.

Use

```
(^283882$|^283778$|^283$)
```

In most regex flavors, `^(283882|283778|283)$` should work, it is really weird you get no matches with it.